# Converting values within a dictionary from strings to floats in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks something like this that was imported from a csv file.

```
 X = {'0':['1.2', '3.2', '4.5', '']}
```

I would like for all of the values within the dictionary to be floats instead of strings but am unsure of how to do this due to the empty quotes at the tail end of the dictionary. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
x2 = {float(k):[float(x) for x in v if x != ''] for k,v in X.iteritems()}
```